# Move shipping calculator on Woocommerce cart page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to move the shipping calculator on the Woocommerce cart paage from inside the cart totals table to below the cart contents table. I could not find any hooks to do this, does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to update the template files. But this depends on what version you are using. Documentation can be found here.

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/

This is a decent guide to give you an idea of what you are looking to do.
https://websitedepot.com/moving-shipping-rates-woocommerce-checkout/

Comment: Be sure to copy the template files to your child theme not edit them directly.

Comment: I have tried to edit the templates but then the calculator gets displayed twice. And the link you provided move the complete shipping details, I only need to move the calculator.

Comment: I added the link to that to give you an idea, and you would also need to remove the calculator from the other part in the main template file. So you are on the right track when you have 2 of them. Just need to figure out where the other one is being displayed and remove it.

Comment: I can't figure out to remove it though. I had added <?php woocommerce_shipping_calculator(); ?> from cart-total-php to a different spot and then it showing up twice...